# Influence of TV spots on the number of visits to the website (time series problem)

Tags: time-series, python, intervention-analysis, marketing

I have hourly data regarding the number of visits to the website. A single record consists of date, time(0-23) and number of visits. In a separate table I have data about the display of advertising spots of my company on various television stations. In this table, a single record consists of the TV station, the emitted program, the date and the hour of the spot emission. I am not able to say how many visits are caused by which station. I would like to check if and which TV stations affect the number of visits to the website.

My first idea is to count how many spots were transmitted at a given hour of the day, divided into stations, and according to what I have found I should investigate seasonality in the time series of visits to the website. And I am not sure what I should follow next? Should I choose some model, e.g. regression (then cyclically code the date and time to deal with the seasonality?) or a model including a feature importance module to check the impact of features? However, I am also not sure if I should use lags (e.g. 24 lags by hour) or use pd.shifts()?

Can I count on a hint on this topic?

Here is simple example of data:
[image]

And my firs idea how to combine this two tables:
[image]

Comment: This is called intervention analysis ... but your problem might be different from a typical version, by having many interventions. I added the tag.

Comment: Can you disaggregate visits by TV market? This would make the problem a bit easier.

Comment: I added simple example of data

Comment: I would call it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribution_(marketing) ,  Its hard to suggest what features without seeing the data.  I believe people treat ad viewing as having  a particular shape with time to ad display.  So assuming linear regression you could eg fit a spline of time to advert + cyclically code date/time ...

Comment: But here I don't have information about success or about user click path

Comment: How long is the series? How many advertising interventions? One interesting predictor could be spending for each add, that must correlated with expected number of viewers ... this is analogous to unmixing or source attribution, so maybe search for those terms ...